# Solicitar una letra al usuario, luego una palabra, y por ultimo decir cuantas veces dicha letra aparece en la palabra

Tags: c, string, bucles, caracteres

Estoy iniciando con programacion en la universidad y me han planteado este problema solo con el uso de la libreria stdio.h. Acá esta el código que estaba intentando pero aun no me funciona Lo que pensaba es primero solicitar la letra y la palabra. Luego hice un ciclo for pero no sabia muy bien con que compararlo pero la idea era que fuera hasta que se cumpliera el numero de veces que la letra aparece en la palabra. Al final queria que si los caracteres de la palabra eran igual a la letra ingresada que la variable b subiera de valor en 1 y que cuando ya no hayan que terminara el loop.`Acá esta el código que estaba intentando pero aun no me funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char letra;
char palabra;
int  i;
int  b = 0;

int main() {
    printf("Ingrese una letra: \n");
    scanf("%s", letra);

    printf("Ingrese una palabra: \n");
    scanf("%s", palabra);
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < letra; i++)
            ;
        {
            if (palabra = letra) {
                b++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el error con el código?

Comment: No lo se. Imagino que es algo que tiene que ver con el orden de cómo coloque las cosas o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Tampoco se como hacer para imprimir a pantalla el valor final con el que quedaria b

Comment: Hola @Martingar_, podrias decir si te fueron utiles las respuestas dadas, gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int contadorLetra = 0;

if (letra >= 'A' && letra <= 'Z')
{
    letra = letra - 'A' + 'a';
}

for (int i = 0; palabra[i] != '\0'; i++) 
{
    char c = palabra[i];
  
    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    {
        c = c - 'A' + 'a';
    }
  
    if(c == letra)
    {
        contadorLetra++;
    }
}

printf("La letra introducida se repite en la palabra %d veces", contadorLetra);
```

Haces un **ciclo for** desde la primera posición de la palabra hasta el último caracter de la palabra. En **C** el caracter que finaliza la cadena es **'\0'**, por lo tanto el **ciclo for** se ejecutará mientras no se encuentre el caracter de finalización de cadena o **'\0'**.

Ya dentro del **ciclo for** preguntarás si la posición actual de la palabra es igual a la letra introducida, de ser igual se incrementa el contador. Por último se imprime el contador, devolviendo de esta forma la cantidad de veces que se repite una letra en la palabra.

El código:

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
{
   c = c - 'A' + 'a';
}
```

Convierte el caracter a minúscula ya que **'E'** no es lo mismo que **'e'**, sino deseas que se convierta a minúscula pues quita la instrucción. Yo transformo cada caracter a minúscula para que todos tengan homogeneidad y todos sean minúscula.

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo tiene multiples errores. Aqui esta corregido con comentarios:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 51 // Usa #define para las constantes porfavor. 
                           // Creeme que te hara mas facil la vida

// De no tener parametros, se coloca void. 
int main(void) {
    // Porfavor coloca las variables dentro de la función, el trabajar con
    // variables globales te dara muchos problemas en el futuro
    char letra;
    char palabra[MAX_STRING_SIZE]; // La palabra tiene que ser un array de caracteres
    size_t  cuenta = 0; // Los tamaños tienen que ser con size_t

    printf("Ingrese una letra: \n");
    scanf("%c", &letra); // Tienes que leer un caracter (%c), y colocarlo en la 
                         // direccion de memoria de letra

    printf("Ingrese una palabra: \n");
    scanf("%s", palabra);

    // El '\0' siempre esta al final de los strings
    for (size_t i = 0; palabra[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        // Comparamos la letra i de palabra con la letra
        if (palabra[i] == letra) {
            cuenta++;
        }
        /*
            De no ser iguales esta parte de tu código:

            } else {
                break;
            }

            Lo que haría seria detener la cuenta con la primera letra
            que no coincida, eso no es lo que quieres
        */
    }

    printf("La letra '%c' aparece %zu veces en '%s'", letra, cuenta, palabra);
}
```

Creo que el problema que tienes es que no tienes suficiente conocimiento de C. Habla con tu profesor para que te ayude con eso. O si no, te recomiendo al 100% el curso CS50. Esta gratuito en internet, y te dará unas buenas bases de C y de programación general.